# How to create custom progress bar with dynamic width

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-constraintlayout

I have to create horizontal progress bar layout design. the challenges is I have to update width of progress bar according to percentage. Second challenge is I have to update color code of progress bar according to percentage. And I have to show percentage view/ text view at end of the progress bar.

Please help to solve this layout design.
For that I have tried default progress bar but its not working may be I missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can Use

**1.** [LinearProgressIndicator](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/progressindicator/LinearProgressIndicator) google material view

Gradle - `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

Code in xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    android:id="@+id/progress1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:trackColor="@color/white"
    app:indicatorColor="@color/teal_200"
    app:trackThickness="30dp"
    android:progress="20"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
```

Set progress to LinearProgressIndicator in Activity class

```
progress1.setProgress(30);
```

**2.** Check this github project - https://github.com/MackHartley/RoundedProgressBar